# "modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread"

Tags: ios, multithreading

I've been able to call the background thread to speed up my application.  However Xcode is throwing me this warning "This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.".  What is going on?

[image]

```
let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {

            //one of these methods is running autolayout in background thread.
            self.hashtagTableAdapter = HashtagTableAdapter(hashtagTableView: hashtagTableView, baseSearchTableSelectItemDelegate: self, hashtagUserDataProviderDelegate: self)
            self.userTableAdapter = UserTableAdapter(userTableView: userTableView, baseSearchTableSelectItemDelegate: self, hashtagUserDataProviderDelegate: self)
            self.phoneBookTableAdapter = PhoneBookTableAdapter(phoneBookTableView: self.phoneTableView, baseSearchTableSelectItemDelegate: self, showInvitedUsers: true)
            self.allTableAdapter = AllTableAdapter(allTableView: allTableView, hashtagUserDataSource: self.userTableAdapter.userTableDataSource, phoneBookDataSource: self.phoneBookTableAdapter.phoneBookDataSource, hashtagUserDataProviderDelegate: self, baseSearchTableSelectItemDelegate: self)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.tableAdapters.append(self.allTableAdapter)
                self.tableAdapters.append(self.hashtagTableAdapter)
                self.tableAdapters.append(self.userTableAdapter)
                self.tableAdapters.append(self.phoneBookTableAdapter)
                self.reloadRecentSearchSectionInAllTab()
                self.queryTF.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        }
```

Comment: The stack seems to be saying that the code to look at is AllTableAdapter::configureTableView.  Apparently, that's being called on a background thread and affecting UIKit.

Comment: I just fixed that and put it on the main thread.. now its saying "_TFC8TimeLoop21PhoneBookTableAdapter9tableViewfTCSo11UITableView21cellForRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_CSo15UITableViewCell + 128".  My cell for row at index path is now affecting UIKit... How do I prevent this?  Make reloadData on main thread?

Comment: Seems reasonable.  `reloadData` causes UI changes as it executes the callbacks for cells to display.

Comment: you da man Phillip.  Fixed my issue.  Thanks!!!!!